# Match name and copy from sheet 1 to sheet 2 next to matched name

Tags: excel, copy, match, vba

I have an Excel sheet with names in column A and an amount in column B for sheet 1.

I have a another sheet that is sheet2 with names in A just like in sheet 1 and column B is blank.

How can I check sheet 1 A name to check with sheet2 A name, if they match then take amount next to that name on sheet1 and copy the amount into the cell next to the matching name on sheet2 next to the name? The names on sheet1 change daily.

I have tried this and get nothing.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
    Dim RowIndex As Integer 
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    RowIndex = Cells.Row
    While DoOne(RowIndex)
        RowIndex = RowIndex + 3
    Wend
End Sub


Function DoOne(RowIndex As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim Key
    Dim Target
    Dim Success
    Success = False
    If Not IsEmpty(Cells(RowIndex, 1).Value) Then
        Key = Cells(RowIndex, 1).Value

        Sheets("sheet2").Select

        Set Target = Columns(2).Find(Key, LookIn:=xlValues)

        If Not Target Is Nothing Then
            Rows(Target.Row).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("Sheet1").Select
            Rows(RowIndex + 1).Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
            Rows(RowIndex + 2).Select
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Success = True
        End If

    End If
    DoOne = Success
End Function
```

Sheet 1:

```
A                                    B

A One Preservation            $16.00 

A&D Recovery, Inc.            $8,108.46 

A&S Field Services, Inc.      $4,941.56 

A&T Jax Inc                   $1,842.48
```

Sheet 2:

```
A                                        B - blank cell

A One Preservation - Calvin & Renee 

A&D Recovery, Inc. - Drew & Adam    

A&S Field Services, Inc. - Aaron    

A&T Jax Inc - Tyson
```

Comment: This code appears to be attempting to copy entire rows. Did you want to copy just the B values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code uses an Index/Match solution to copy the matched B values from sheet1 from sheet2. The code will work with variable sheet names

1. blank cells are ignored
2. Non-matches on the second sheet are flagged as "no match".
3. The code removes the formulae from column B on the second sheet by updating with values only

   **Update**: if you second sheet names are the same as sheet1, but have a " -some text" to the right, then use this updated part of the code

   ```
    With rng1.Offset(0, 1)
       .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]<>"""",IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(LEFT(RC[-1],FIND("" -"",RC[-1])-1),'" & ws1.Name & "'!C[-1],0))),INDEX('" & ws1.Name & "'!C,MATCH(LEFT(RC[-1],FIND("" -"",RC[-1])-1),'" & ws1.Name & "'!C[-1],0)),""no match""),"""")"
       .Value = .Value
   End With
   ```

   original

   ```
    Sub QuickUpdate()
       Dim ws1 As Worksheet
       Dim ws2 As Worksheet
       Dim rng1 As Range
       Set ws1 = Sheets(1)
       Set ws2 = Sheets(2)
       Set rng1 = ws2.Range(ws2.[a1], ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
       With rng1.Offset(0, 1)
           .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]<>"""",IF(NOT(ISNA(MATCH(RC[-1],'" & ws1.Name & "'!C[-1],0))),INDEX('" & ws1.Name & "'!C,MATCH(RC[-1],'" & ws1.Name & "'!C[-1],0)),""no match""),"""")"
           .Value = .Value
       End With
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: Thanks, but it only works if both cells match exactly.  Is there a way to match by key words?

Comment: Ok, given that clarification which sheet contains the text that should be partially matched in the other sheet? Or is it more complex than that? Examples would help. cheers

Comment: sheet 1 looks like this:                                             A One Preservation  $16.00 
 A&D Recovery, Inc.  $8,108.46 
 A&S Field Services, Inc.  $4,941.56 
 A&T Jax Inc  $1,842.48                                                      sheet 2 looks like this:                                                     A One Preservation - Calvin & Renee 
A&D Recovery, Inc. - Drew & Adam 
A&S Field Services, Inc. - Aaron  
A&T Jax Inc - Tyson , sheet 2 has some cells highlighted blue and some names in red, formatted different from sheet 1

Comment: it still doesn't work, unless the names are exactly the same.

Comment: did you substitute the updated portion into the original code?

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, I found why it wasn't working, it was due to a space in front of the names in sheet1.  Again, I think you so, very much "brettdj"

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the VLOOKUP function?

Sheet1 has your names in column A, and values in column B.
Sheet2 has your lookup names in column A, and in column B, you put:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!$A$1:$B$n,2,FALSE)
```

Where 'n' is the number of rows in your Sheet1 table.

The only issue with this is it will put an #N/A if it can't find the name in Sheet1. There's likely a way to put in an alternate entry using a conditional.

Comment: the names are always changing daily and the number of names are changing daily also.